# Django | Как реализовать счетчик просмотров БЕЗ НАКРУТКИ!

Tags: python, django

Как реализовать счетчик просмотров при этом исключая возможность НАКРУТКИ (простые варианты аля counter +=1 не канает) через reload браузера.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    total_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def counter(self):
        return self.total_views += 1
```

Comment: Привяжите счётчик к `IP`.

Comment: @AlexFox, вот у вас есть счетчик просмотров при получении страницы? В метод его получения/обработки добавьте получение текущего IP клиента и сохраняйте это в базу данных. Например, в таблицу где ключом будет id страницы (или ссылка на нее) и IP. Тогда, через эту таблицу сможете узнать какие страницы смотрел конкретный IP или например сколько IP посещало страницу (т.е. счетчик просмотров)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я все таки разобрался, и хотел бы чтобы люди которые столкнулись с такой проблемой получили решение.

В файле *models.py*:

```
from django.db import models

class Ip(models.Model): # наша таблица где будут айпи адреса
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.ip

class Post(models.Model): # модель у которой будем считать просмотры
    ...
    views = models.ManyToManyField(Ip, related_name="post_views", blank=True)
```

Регистрируем модели в админке *admin.py*:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Ip

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Ip)
```

В файле *views.py* создаем метод получения айпи пользователя и наши вьюшки:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from videos.models import Post, Ip

# Метод для получения айпи
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') # В REMOTE_ADDR значение айпи пользователя
    return ip

# Главная страница тут рендерим все посты
def home_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    context = {
        'posts' : posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)

# Страница самого поста
def post_view(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    ip = get_client_ip(request)

    if Ip.objects.filter(ip=ip).exists():
        post.views.add(Ip.objects.get(ip=ip))
    else:
        Ip.objects.create(ip=ip)
        post.views.add(Ip.objects.get(ip=ip))  
    
    context = {
        'post' : post,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/post.html', context)
```

Мой файл *urls.py*:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import  (
    home_view, 
    post_view, 
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name='home-view'),
    path('posts/<str:slug>/', post_view, name='post'),
]
```

Для того чтобы получить количество просмотров в файле *models.py* в модели *Post* создаем метод который будет нам возвращать кол-во просмотров:

```
def total_views(self):
    return self.views.count()
```

Шаблон *main/home.html*:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="content">
    <div class="grid-container">
    {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="item">
                <a href="/posts/{{post.slug}}/">
                    <p>{{post.title}}<p>
                    <p>Просмотры : {{post.total_views}}</p> <!-- Просмотры -->
                </a>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Шаблон *main/post.html*:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="post">
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>Просмотры : {{post.total_views}}</p> <!-- Просмотры -->
    <hr>
    <p>Описание: {{post.desc}}</p>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Так-то так, надеюсь что если у кого-то возникнет такой вопрос, он наткнется на мое решение и оно ему поможет. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Спасибо за то, что поделились своей реализацией! Кстати, можно немного упростить `post_view`, если использовать `Ip.objects.get_or_create(ip=ip)`.